# express-session session is not consistent

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, session, express

In my project i am using nodejs (express), react js  and socket.io to develop a chatting application. But i am not able to get "correct sessionid" inside my socket function (io.use).

In server.js file there are routes and functions to handle socket connections.
In my project i had started my express-session inside login.js file.
Then after successfull login...i am redirecting to home.js, which intern returns home.html.
home.html contains js file, which is having react code and also have socket connections.

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');
var DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "bin");
var express = require('express');

//Getting session store
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var sessionStore = new session.MemoryStore();
var handshakeData ={};  
var cookie = require('cookie');

//Importing routes
 var login = require('./routes/login.js'); 
 var registration = require('./routes/registration.js');
 var home = require('./routes/home.js'); 


//Getting cookies from request header. so that from it we can get sessionid. 
io.use(function(socket, next) { 

  handshakeData = socket.request;
  var cookies = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);

//Bringing sessionid and storing in a global variable
console.log("***********************Server*********************");
console.log("");
console.log('All cookies parsed in io.use ( %s )', JSON.stringify(cookies));
handshakeData.sessionID = cookies['connect.sid'].split('.')[0].split(':'[1];
console.log('All cookies parsed at server ( %s )', JSON.stringify(cookies));
console.log('Session id at server cookie value in io.use( %s )', 
JSON.stringify(handshakeData.sessionID));
next();
});

//Bringing session data by sending "sessionid" to sessionStore 
(MemoryStore)place 
io.on('connection', function(socket){

  sessionStore.get(handshakeData.sessionID, function (err, session) {
            handshakeData.session = session;

            //Now we can retrieve all session data. But sessionID sent was 
not correct     

    }); 

console.log('user connected');
socket.on('new message', function(msg){
console.log('Server recieved new message: '+msg);
io.emit('new message', msg);
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
console.log('user disconnected');
});
});

app.use('/', login);
app.use('/registration', registration); 
app.use('/home', home); 


http.listen(8080, function(){
console.log("listening on port 8080");
});
```

login.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
var session = require('express-session');
var sessionStore = new session.MemoryStore();
var login_success = 0;

router.use(cookieParser());

router.use(session({ cookie: {
    maxAge  : 24*60*60*1000
 },
  store: sessionStore,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  secret: '1234567890QWERT'
  }));

router.get('/', function(req, res){

  console.log("Actual session id before login: "+ req.sessionID);   
//Clearing cookies at client side.
    res.clearCookie("login_message");
    res.clearCookie("connect.sid");
    res.clearCookie("io");
    res.clearCookie("user_name");
    res.clearCookie("user_id");


if (login_success == 2)
  {
     res.cookie('login_message', 'incorrectCredentials');
     login_success = 0;
  }

  res.sendFile(path.join(SRC_DIR,"login.html"));
 // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../bin', 'login.html'));

});





router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){


console.log("database called");

//Fetching form data
   var username = req.body.loginusername;  
   var password  = req.body.loginpassword;


 //Connection string to datanbase
   var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
   var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/WebChat";

 //Comparing username and password.
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
       if (err) throw err;
       var query = { email: username, password: password };
       db.collection("Profile").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
          db.close();
          if (result.length != 0)
          {
              console.log("login success");
              login_success = 1;

              //Setting session variables
              req.session.userid = username;
              req.session.username= result[0].firstname;

              console.log("***********************Login*********************");
              console.log("");

              console.log("Actual session id at login: "+ req.sessionID);
              console.log("Session userid at server set to :"+ req.session.userid);
              console.log("Session name at server set to :"+ req.session.username);

              //res.sendFile(path.join(SRC_DIR,"home.html"));
              //  res.status(200).send(req.session);

                   console.log("Session reload called");
                   res.redirect('/home');

          }
          else
          {

              //**It is for when user come to login page with entering wrong credentials
              login_success = 2;
              console.log("login failed");
              res.redirect('http://localhost:8080');

          }


        });
    });
```

});

```
//export this router to use in our server.js
module.exports = router;
```

home.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require("path");
var SRC_DIR=path.join(__dirname, "../src/views");

var session = require('express-session');
 cookie = require('cookie');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var sessionStore = new session.MemoryStore();
var handshakeData ={};

router.use(cookieParser());


router.use(session({ cookie: {
    maxAge  : 24*60*60*1000
  },
  store: sessionStore,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  secret: '1234567890QWERT'
  }));  



router.get('/', function(req, res){


 //setting cookie at client side
  res.clearCookie("user_id");
  res.clearCookie("user_name");

  res.cookie('user_id', req.session.userid);
  res.cookie('user_name', req.session.username);


 // res.status(200).send(req.session);
  console.log(" session reload called");
  setTimeout(function(){
  res.sendFile(path.join(SRC_DIR,"home.html"));
  }, 5000);

  console.log("***********************Home*********************");
  console.log("");
  console.log("Actual session id at home: "+ req.sessionID);
  console.log("Cookie userid at client set to :"+ req.session.userid);
  console.log("Cookie username at client set to :"+ req.session.username);


});


//export this router to use in our server.js
module.exports = router;
```

home.jsx (client side file)

```
class Home extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {messages: [],socket: io.connect('http://localhost:8080')};
this.send = this.send.bind(this)

  }
}
export default Home
```

Ouput when exicuting "node server.js":

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WHIp.png)

In the above output...
 1. login page we got two different session ids (before login and after login).I don't know why this is happening
 2. While accessing the session variable inside "server.js", in "io.use" function... we again getting old session id, which was set before login.But with this i can't get my session variable. Because i need to pass new session variable in order to access session variable inside sessionStore.get.

Please help. i have been trying this for 3 days. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: wats the version of `express-session` ?

Comment: i am using express version 4.15.0

Comment: im looking for `express-session` version.

Comment: it's  express-session@1.15.5

Comment: Try initiating cookie parser using your secret with the same secert you use for `express-session` like `router.use(cookieParser('1234567890QWERT'));
`

Comment: I tried that. But still still login.js creating two different sessionids.